# How do I easily refresh my AJAX results with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, reload

I am writing a script that gets chat messages automatically from an ajax call.  I want to be able to refresh the content every 1000 ms, however, setInterval doesn't seem to work well.  Since my script loops through results of an xml file and then adds content to my html with append, it just keeps adding the same results over and over.  Can anyone think of a way that I can add only results that haven't already been loaded to my HTML?

```
$(function(){
     $('#chat_messages').ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: $('#chat_messages').attr("rel"),
            dataType: "xml",
            cache: false,
            statusCode: {
                404: function(){alert("404 not found!")}
            }
        })
        .done(function(xml){
            var sample = $("#sample").html();
                $(xml).find("message").each(function(){
                    var new_content = sample.replace('{author}', $(this).find("author_name").text());
                    new_content = new_content.replace('{content}', $(this).find("content").text());
                    new_content = new_content.replace('{datesent}', $(this).find("datesent").text());
                    $('#chat_messages').append(new_content);
                });
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert("Ajax failed!");
        })
     }, 1000);
     });
});
```

HTML

```
    <!-- Sample message. -->
    <div id="sample" style="display: none;">

        <div class="block1" id="{message_id}">

                <h1>{author}</h1>

                <p>{content}</p>

                <h3>{datesent}</h3>

       </div>

    </div>
```

XML:

```
<message id="6">
<author_id>3</author_id>
<author_name>Scottyboy1988</author_name>
<recipient_id>1</recipient_id>
<recipient_name>HigH VolTagE</recipient_name>
<content>You're even more awesome!</content>
<datesent>38 Minutes</datesent>
<status>unread</status>
</message>
```

Comment: do you have access to the server-side code?

Answer (score 0):

You have message id so when you are loading update the last shown id in a js array variable then in next calls check the last shown value if found continue else show the message body...